# Matrix format in Latex

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How can a matrix be written in LaTeX? I have tried to use `\begin{matrix}` but I need to write the matrix below and I cannot understand how to fill it up exactly as this.
[image]

Comment: `\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{matrix}` should work

Comment: Basic guidelines are at the [LaTeX wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

Comment: I have already seen those but I am getting a lot of missing $ etc

Comment: @user1930901: You have to wrap a math environment around `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}`, say $...$ or `\(...\)`  of course

Comment: You can also use the pmatrix environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -(\lambda_1 + \mu_1) & \lambda_1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -(\lambda_2 + \mu_2) & \lambda_2 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -(\lambda_{n-1} + \mu_{n-1}) & \lambda_{n-1} & \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -\mu_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! can you label such equation? since I did \label{2} before \end{equation} but nothing is showing

Comment: @user1930901 use the unstarred version: `\begin{equation}`, not `\begin{equation*}`.